# echo %JAVA_HOME% works in cmd, but not in git bash

Tags: java, shell, command-prompt, git-bash, java-home

Windows 10 user. I recently installed git for the first time, but ran into a peculiar issue. I was told that I needed to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable if I wanted to use java within git.

I was able to get `JAVA_HOME` properly changed for command prompt, but I couldn't get the same change to show up in git bash. Typing in `echo %JAVA_HOME%` would return a proper path in command prompt, but it would return `%JAVA_HOME%` in git bash.

I went into system settings and changed the system variable so that `JAVA_HOME` was pointing to my jdk. I updated the `PATH` variable in both system and environment variables to point to the bin and the jdk. I closed and reopened both git bash and command prompt. I restarted my machine, and even reinstalled both git and my jdk. I took my jdk from Java 10.0.2 down to the latest java 8 (171).

None of it has worked. I've gone through countless SO posts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with git, only bash. Learn shell syntax.

Comment: You're correct, and believe me, I will. It was just something I couldn't see as a beginner, but now I know to really watch out for the syntax.

Comment: The shell used by git is a version of the ***Linux*** shell and is supported under Cygwin, which provides a Linux-style command line.  This is a completely different environment and expects Linux style environment variables.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I'd heard talk about git and cygwin being compatible, but I didn't know that git was originally a Linux shell. I guess I should make it a point to look into the history of software before trying to work with it. Would you recommend that I work with Cygwin instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out, (git) ***BASH TERMINAL*** uses a completely different syntax to do echo than ***COMMMANDLINE TERMINAL***.

I had been doing `echo %JAVA_HOME%` when I should have been doing `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

I couldn't see that I was supposed to be using $ and not % sign because the symbols looked so similar in my font. I only found out after copy/pasting an answer out of frustration into bash and having it magically work when it hadn't worked prior.

But yes, the answer is to use `$` and not `%` because they mean completely different things. Git bash uses $, command prompt uses %. You'd think they'd just use the same symbol to get the job done.

Comment: Git **bash** is a Windows version of the bash shell that comes from the Unix/Linux world, where indeed environment variables are prefixed with a $. I have no idea why Microsoft decided to use %, just as I don't have an idea why the use \ where Unix used /. There are probably/maybe valid reasons :)

Comment: I guess it does make sense then. I wasn't aware of the origins of git bash, so I couldn't see why they would choose to do things differently.

Comment: @fvu MS-DOS didn't have directories, but had options for command line - (like now dir /w) - so when they added directories, they were feqd and had to keep options working by using \ for directories.

Comment: In bash you don't have a trailing $ after the variable name

Comment: @phuclv touche. Edited.

Comment: @fvu [everything traces back to CP/M](https://superuser.com/q/176388/241386), including drive letters. Regarding the `%` symbol I've asked a question for it [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7270/1981)